# Python `eval`: "invalid syntax" error, when trying to create class attributes programmatically?

Tags: python

I have a lot of class attributes that I want to create, so I decided to use a function to do so:

```
def make_index_variables(self):
    for index, label in enumerate(self.variable_labels):
        eval('self.' + label + '_index = ' + str(index))
```

If earlier, I defined:

```
self.variable_labels = ['x', 'y']
```

I get an error message like this:

```
eval('self.' + label + '_index = ' + str(index))

    self.x_index = 0
                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am beginning to realize that using `setattr` is probably better than using `eval` (but I am not sure). In any case, why does `eval` raise this error?

Comment: Use `exec` for "commands" (like `x = 5`), and `eval` for expressions (like `2**5`). And yes, using `setattr` is definitely better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do `exec` instead of `eval`

```
exec('self.' + label + '_index = ' + str(index))
```

`eval` will evaluate a expression, not run it like you want. 
Think of `eval` like the argument of a `if` statement.

Also, if you want to set attributes of a class, you should definitely use `setattr` instead. 
Actually, 99% of time there are better options for what you want rather than using `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
setattr(self, name + "_index", index)
```

Eval evaluates an expression. Different from C, in Python an assignment is a statement, not an expression (you cannot write `c = (a = b) == None`, for example. The variant `a = b = 3` is somewhat special syntax. It does actually not pass the value assigned to b , but the value on the right side (yes, this is a subtle, but important difference).

If it just for an index, there may be better versions which do not pullute the namespace, however.